# In PyCharm HOWTO make plots be in scientific view and not in a new window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I would like to plot results in the 'plots' tab in scientific view like in that help post:
[Scientific Mode Tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-tutorial.html)
But instead I'm getting regular plot (in a new window)[image]

What I'm doing wrong? I'm using code from tutorial (link above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 years late on this, but hopefully this helps someone else who stumbles across this issue.

I had this problem on MacOSX with PyCharm version 2021.3.3

At first, I was using TkAgg as the backend for Matplotlib, but apparently this causes plots to open in new windows, even if the scientific tool window box is checked.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

I deleted the previous two lines of code and got the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'backend_interagg' has no attribute 'FigureCanvas'
```

After troubleshooting and scouring the internet for hours, I was finally able to resolve the error and get SciView working in PyCharm **without unnecessary figure windows** by simply downgrading matplotlib to version 3.5.3

Steps:

1. PyCharm -> Preferences -> Project -> Interpreter
2. Scroll down and double-click "matplotlib" package
3. Check "specify version" box and switch from 3.6.x to 3.5.3

Answer (score 3):

```
Go to Settings -> Tools -> Python Scientific
```

and tick Show plots in toolwindow.

[image]

Comment: that option do nothing in my case

Comment: do you have anaconda?

Comment: according to the jet brains ide support it does works on pure virtual environment. but not on conda. 

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000742510-Unable-to-use-mathplotlib-in-scientific-mode
checkout the second last comment here.

Comment: or you can choose and use the existing interpreter when in new project -> scientific in pycharm.  :)